# Time zone problem: Etc/GMT-14 equals GMT+14. Why?

Tags: android, timezone

I enumerated all available time zones on Android 12 by this code:

```
String[] ids = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
```

and found ids from "Etc/GMT+12" to "Etc/GMT-14" but in fact they equal "GMT-12" to "GMT+14". For example "**Etc/GMT-7**" equals "**GMT+7**".

Why Android uses negative names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These names are offered by the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) which underlies the time zone implementation on Android.

The database has the [following comments](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/main/etcetera#L37-L43) referring to these names/definitions:

> Be consistent with POSIX TZ settings in the Zone names,
> even though this is the opposite of what many people expect.
> POSIX has positive signs west of Greenwich, but many people expect
> positive signs east of Greenwich.  For example, TZ='Etc/GMT+4' uses
> the abbreviation "-04" and corresponds to 4 hours behind UT
> (i.e. west of Greenwich) even though many people would expect it to
> mean 4 hours ahead of UT (i.e. east of Greenwich).

So IANA does it this way because POSIX does it this way.  [The POSIX spec for the environment variable `TZ` is](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> offset
>
> ...
>
> The minutes (mm) and seconds (ss) are optional. The hour (hh) shall be
> required and may be a single digit. The offset following std shall be
> required. If no offset follows dst, the alternative time is assumed to
> be one hour ahead of standard time. One or more digits may be used;
> the value is always interpreted as a decimal number. The hour shall be
> between zero and 24, and the minutes (and seconds)-if present-between
> zero and 59. The result of using values outside of this range is
> unspecified. **If preceded by a '-', the timezone shall be east of the
> Prime Meridian; otherwise, it shall be west** (which may be indicated by
> an optional preceding '+' ).

(emphasis added by me)

For your amusement, note that POSIX is not self-consistent.  [Here is the POSIX spec for `strftime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html):

> z
>
> Replaced by the offset from UTC in the ISO 8601:2000 standard format (
> +hhmm or -hhmm ), or by no characters if no timezone is determinable. For example, **"-0430" means 4 hours 30 minutes behind UTC (west of
> Greenwich)**.

Comment: Thank you. Widget AnalogClock may use time zone "+0300", but TextClock can use only "Etc/GMT-3". I think this is not good practice.

Comment: Use of POSIX time zones, or time zones derived from POSIX time zones is generally not good practice except for rare and special circumstances.  The IANA time zones that are named after region/city generally more accurately model actual time zones in real world use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones